# Protobuf (de)serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a class setup like this (I removed a lot of the other properties since they don't relate to my question...):

```
public class Record : IRecord
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of recovery record and data needed to recover this record.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public IRecord Entry { get; private set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object Entry
    {
        get { return Entry; }
    }
}

[ProtoContract
    , ProtoInclude(2, typeof(CaseRecord))
    , ProtoInclude(3, typeof(UserRecord))
]
public interface IRecord: IEntry
{
}

public interface IEntry
{
    long EntryId { get; set; }
    long DataSourceId { get; set; }
}

public class UserRecord : RecordEntry<UserRecord> 
{
    // ...other datamembers...

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override long EntryId { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override long DataSourceId { get; set; } 
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class RecordEntry<T> : RType<T>, IRecord
    where T : RType<T>, new()
{
    // other datamembers...
    public abstract long EntryId { get; set; }
    public abstract long DataSourceId { get; set; }
}
```

I (de)serialize streams of the records like so:

`Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(_stream, record, PrefixStyle.Base128);`

`Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Record>(_stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);`

When I try and deserialize though, my `Record` object (which is of type `UserRecord`) returns values of 0 for `EntryId` and `DataSourceId` and I'm not entirely sure why. I removed the `[IgnoreDataMember]` from the `Entry` and `DataSource` id's but i still get a value of 0 on deserilization. All the other properties of the object are populated correctly.

the user record is created like so in my `[TestMethod]`...

```
userRecord1 = new UserRecord()
{
    // ...other datamembers
    EntryId = 123456789,
    DataSourceId = 123456789,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://thwadi.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-protobuff-net-with-inheritance.html

Found the above article and added the `ProtoMember` attribute to `EntryId` and `DataSourceId` and I was able to get the correct values.